# Is there a way to write to a DB using a specific batch size?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

I'm running the code below and it works, but it's super slow.  I think the default size of write chunks is 1,000 records.  I want to up this to 500,000 records chunk.  I did some research on this and it seems like this can be done, but I didn't see any sample code that does what I want, and all my attempts to modify this code have failed.

```
url = "jdbc:sqlserver://server_name.database.windows.net:1433;databaseName=db_name"
props = {"user": "usr","password": "pwd"}


df.write.mode('append').jdbc(url,"dbo.table_name",properties=props)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`props = {"user": "usr","password": "pwd", "batchsize" : "500000"}`